# Foursquare API results not same as data on Foursquare site

Tags: api, foursquare

I'm trying to get comments for a [specific restaurant](https://foursquare.com/v/oola-restaurant--bar/417ee500f964a520d71d1fe3) using Foursquare API but I'm not getting same (all) results as they are on the Foursquare site.

I used the Foursquare API Explorer but it did not return all comments as they appear on Foursquare.

Comment: Hi akdotcom, I'd like to get TIPS :D, actually as I can see now, it seems to be that results are limited to 20 rows, is there a way to pull at least last 20 rows using a venue ID if i can't pull all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/tips